# Strange behavior of HTML link tag

Tags: html, uri, httprequest, quotes

We came across a strange behavior while using html  tag. Actually the issue was because of improper usage of the tag. As a result of that, the page was getting submitted 3 times in Mozilla Firefox and 2 times in IE7. Here is the issue.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Style" href=''/css/image.css'>
```

This was the code that we were using in one of our J2EE application. When we inspected the request and response (using HTTP Watch), we found out that the page was requested 3 times from the server. We found out that the additional "**quote**" after `href=` is causing the problem. We were not able to find out the reason why this was causing multiple page submissions. Is it because, the additional quote makes the `href` empty and because of that browser tries to load the `styleclass` from the same URL that loaded the page? 
Can someone please help to find out the reason why this is happening? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's called an "element", not a tag. Proper quoting (i.e. using `"` instead of two apostrophes) will fix the problem.

Comment: Proper quoting fixed the problem. But I'm more interested in finding out why the additional single quote is causing the problem.:)

Comment: The above is certainly a tag as well as an element. Well, it would be, if it didn't have some invalid markup (`/css/image.css'`) inside it, following the empty attribute `href` attribute value.

Comment: I tested this out and it did not reload multiple times for me.  This leads me to believe that it might be caused by a tag following that tag, possibly imposed upon by the quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="mainOutterTable">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table class="layoutColumn" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width:100%;" valign="top">
                                    <table class="layoutRow" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" width="910">
                                                <table class="layoutColumn" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="width:100%;" valign="top">
                                                            <table class="layoutRow" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="top" width="294">
                                                                        <table class="layoutColumn" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td style="width:100%;" valign="top">
                                                                                    <a name="7_N1K8HIC0GOO780I2B1KASD3047"></a>
                                                                                    <div class="wpsPortletBody">
                                                                                        This is a sample textf 3.
                                                                                        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Style" href=''/>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I was able to reproduce the problem on a test page.[image]

This is mentioned in Section 5.2 of http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#sec-5.2
If the Relative path is empty, then the target URI is the base path.
    if (R.path == "") then
                   T.path = Base.path;

Answer (score 1):

this explanation came from [this article on Yahoo Developer site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html). Section **Avoid Empty Image src**:

`When an empty string is encountered as a URI, it is considered a relative URI and is resolved according to the algorithm defined in section 5.2. This specific example, an empty string, is listed in section 5.4.`

Although it still not clear whether this behavior affect `href` or not (the article mainly concerned on empty `src`). But looks like it does:

`Hopefully, browsers will not have this problem in the future. Unfortunately, there is no such clause for <script src=""> and <link href="">. Maybe there is still time to make that adjustment to ensure browsers don't accidentally implement this behavior.`

**note:** I never encounter such behavior so it's just theoretical answer :)